# How to execute .exe file from repo on azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an .exe file of my console app in a repository and I want to run it on a pipeline.
I tried using a cmd task but it kept failing, saying it's not finding my .exe file.

Basically I tried the steps on [here](https://devsdaily.com/azure-devops-how-to-run-console-applications-on-azure-pipeline/)

when I followed the steps on the link above exactly, the log shows this

```
/home/vsts/work/_temp/7b7bec7c-25c2-4077-bdfb-052d01fcc054.sh: line 1: ConsoleApp.exe: command not found    
##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
```

then I tried changing the script,
from simply

```
ConsoleApp.exe
```

into

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ConsoleApp.exe
```

then it threw me another error

```
/home/vsts/work/_temp/da794edd-60c7-43c5-bd5d-eeff7fbefa46.sh: line 1: /home/vsts/work/1/s/ConsoleApp.exe: Permission denied
##[error]Bash exited with code '126'.
```

and now I'm starting to run out of ideas on why it's happening, so if anyone could help me out that would be great.

Comment: Would you be able to update your post with screenshots of your steps & agent configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my test, I could reproduce this issue in Linux Agent.

[image]

To solve this issue, you need to check the following two fields to use the **Windows-2019 Agent**.

- **Pipeline  -> Agent Specification**

[image]

- Agent job -> Agent Specification

[image]

By default, it will follow the settings in Agent Job scope.

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reproduce steps from the [article](https://devsdaily.com/azure-devops-how-to-run-console-applications-on-azure-pipeline/), you have to use:

1. [Command Line Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic)
2. Windows-2019 vmImage

> Finally, I setup a pipeline with a “Command Line Script” task to run
> the executable. Since it’s a Windows executable file, I set the Agent
> specification to “Windows-2019”.

In your case, you use a Linux vmImage.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm already using Command Line Script. And I'm not sure why it's a Linux vmImage since I've already set the specification to Windows-2019, same as the article

Comment: @Shadizz, add your pipeline configuration to the question because it reports `da794edd-60c7-43c5-bd5d-eeff7fbefa46.sh`. That command from a linux environment.